How to generate a trail behind an object moving through lines
Question related to a previous post, where I asked how to animate a sphere (or an other object ) passing through lines, with geometrynodes.
Now I would like that the sphere leaves a sort of trail behind itself as it passes through those lines,
as in this Tame Impala's album cover here :

It could have something to do with Simulation Zone, but never used it before..
Thanks in advance !
@bunchofbradys

probably could be done with displacement

This uses the same setup as the answer in your previous question, but using a simulation zone when doing the Set Position.
There are a couple of main things happening here. Based on the distance to the spheres position, we initialize an attribute is_active. If a point is active, then there is another attribute called age which increases by 1 for each loop in the simulation.
All points slowly decay back to their original positions p_0, and while a point is active it also gets some noise offset applied to it's position on the XY plane. Because of this, we can see the trail behind where the sphere was, as active points slowly decay back to their original positions with noise noise added on top.




Thanks again @bunchofbradys , works like a charm !
